# PHP SESSIONS values not sticking

Tags: php

I am trying to create a simple login and protect some pages in a folder. Once the user puts in the username/pwd, the page redirects them to the `index.php` in another folder.

In the `index.php`, I am trying to validate the login. The code here is to test to see if there are any values in the SESSION parameters.

When I redirect to `index.php`, nothing shows up.

login.php

```
 <?php
   ob_start();
   session_start();
     if(isset($_GET[redirect_url])) {
         $_SESSION[redirect] = $_GET[redirect_url];
     }
?>

<h2>Enter Username and Password</h2> 
      <div class = "container form-signin">

         <?php
            $msg = '';           
            if (isset($_POST["login"]) && !empty($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])) {
                        if ($_POST["username"] == '1234' && $_POST["password"] == '1234') {
                $_SESSION["login"] = true;
                $_SESSION["timeout"] = time();
                                if(isset($_SESSION["redirect"])) {
                                    $url = $_SESSION["redirect"] . "/index.php";
                                    header("Location:" . $url);
                                    unset($_SESSION["redirect"]);
                                    }
                                }
                            else {
                  $msg = "Login Failed!";
               }
            }
         ?>
      </div> <!-- /container -->

      <div class = "container">

         <form class = "form-signin" role = "form" 
            action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); 
            ?>" method = "post">
            <h4 class = "form-signin-heading"><?php echo $msg; ?></h4>
            <input type = "text" class = "form-control" 
               name = "username" placeholder = "username" 
               required autofocus></br>
            <input type = "password" class = "form-control"
               name = "password" placeholder = "password" required>
            <button class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type = "submit" 
               name = "login">Login</button>
         </form>

         Click here to clean <a href = "logout.php" tite = "Logout">Session.

      </div>
```

redirected page:

```
<?php
  echo $_SESSION["login"];
  echo $_SESSION["timeout"];
  exit; ?>
```

I just get a blank screen. I do not sure why non of the values are sticking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `session_start();` on the second page.

```
<?php
  session_start();
  echo $_SESSION["login"];
  echo $_SESSION["timeout"];
  exit; ?>
```